# External door handle crack

Tags: doors, crack

My front door handle (external side) has a crack which makes it loose wobble and we’re worried it will fall off and we’ll get locked out. Is there a way to fix/ replace or do we need a professional?

Thanks

[enter image description[image] here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2z3C.jpg)

Comment: A picture showing the whole handle, plus measurements (hold a ruler next to it for the picture) would help a lot. Does this handle rotate or is it fixed (can't tell from this picture)?

Answer (score 4):

Unscrew the hex screw on the top. Remove the handle and bring it to the store to find a replacement.

As a temporary fix use a hose clamp then slip it over and tighten, to prevent accidents.

[image: hose clamp]

Answer (score 3):

Likely the handle is thin brass. I think its time for a new handle. And repair that does not look obvious would likely cost more than a new handle.